# Problems making elements fit for mobile first/media query

Tags: html, css, media

I never finished my web-integrator education but i am now a mediagraphics intern and i offered to code a bit in css and html. So i am very rusty and this project has been just as much a refresher of knowledge as it has been a proper project. So be nice please.

I am making the site responsive however I am having a problem coding for the phone screen size.
To the right of my content the background image continues, allowing you to scroll sideways. I simply can't find out what's causing this. Images and everything are edited to fit the width there.

I have one suspicion, that I might have messed up completely with the width of the pixels. I have made it fit the screen but should i forget that and use the actual widths of the phone screen? Just seems so small and it appears to work fine with 1090px width here, it is just the background that push to the side.

[image: Screenshot of the extra space on the right.]

[image: How it is supposed to look]

This is my css code for the media query I am using for the phone.

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    /* Splitters */

    .splitter1 {
        visibility: hidden;
        height:0;
        width:0;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    .splitter1mobile {
        visibility: visible;
        height:250px;
        width:1090px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    .splitter2 {
        visibility: hidden;
        height:0;
        width: 0;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    .splitter2mobile {
        visibility:visible;
        height:250px;
        width:1090px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    .splitter3 {
        visibility: hidden;
        height:0;
        width: 0;
        z-index:1000;

    }

    .splitter3mobile {
        visibility: visible;
        height:250px;
        width:1090px;
        margin:0 0 7px 0;
        padding:0;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .splitter4 {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .splitter4mobile {
        visibility: visible;
        height:250px;
        width:1090px;
        margin:-2px 0 0 0;
        padding:0;
        z-index: 1000;
    }



.orangesplitter {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    margin-bottom:-11px;
}

.greysplitter {
    height:239px;
    width:100%;
    margin:-19px 0 26px 0;

}


    footer { 
    width:86.5%;
}

    .Element-header {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

    .Element-header--fixed {
      top: 0;
      position: fixed;
}

    /*------------- Body --------------*/

    .fysphone {
        margin-left:57px;
        margin-top:112px;
        visibility: visible;
        width:56%;
        height:45%;
    }

    .fysphone img {
        visibility: visible;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
    }

    .fysimgbox {
        display:none;
    }

    .jonimgbox {
        visibility: hidden;
        width:0;
        height:0;
    }

    .contentwrapper {
        width:100%;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    .textbox {
        width:90%;
    }

    .jonimgboxphone {
        margin-top:22px;
    }

    .jonnicephone {
        margin:0 0 0 100px;
    }

    .jontitelphone {
        margin-left:199px;
    }

    header {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        z-index: 1000;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        width:1090px;
        height:265px;
        position:fixed;
        box-shadow:0 5px 15px 0 #7d7b7c;
    }


    body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1090px;
        height:8227px;
        background-image: url(img/wallbgfadedphone.png);
        background-repeat:repeat;
        background-blend-mode: overlay;
    }

    .imgmbox {
        margin-left:0;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    /*----- Google Maps -----*/
    iframe {
        margin-top:150px;
        margin-right:20px;
        width:500px;
        height:350px;

    }

    .wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width:100%;
      height: 8227px;
    }
/*------------- Header ------------*/


/*------------- Header Navbar ------------*/

    .Hnavbar {
        margin-top:0;
        height:101px;
        width:100%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(125,123,124,.9);
        background-image:url(img/wallbg.jpg);

    }   

    .nav1 {
        margin-left:-26px;
    }

    nav ul {
        height:101px;
        float:left;
        margin:0;
        width:100%;
    }
    nav ul li {
        margin-left:30px;
        margin-top:18px;
        float:left;
        height:30px;
        list-style: none;
        border-radius: 9px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-family:Exo;
        color: #dedede;
        padding:5px 23px 5px 23px;
        border-top:1px solid #dedede;
        border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .fblink {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:150px;
        margin-top:15px;
        display:none;
    }

.fbicon:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
}


/*** Content Block ***/
.contentblock {
    width:100%;
    height:1200px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.8);
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:0.9;        
}


.contentblock1 {
    width:100%;
    height:1239px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.8);
    display:flex;
    opacity:0.9;
}    

.contentblock2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height:1971px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.8);
    opacity:0.9;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#contentblock3 {
    width: 100%;
    height:1120px;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.8);
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:0.9;

}

/*** Anchor Menupoint Scrollpositioner ***/
.anchor {
    display:none;
    height:265px;
    margin-top: -265px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

/*** Om Text ***/
.textbox p {
    font-family:Exo-Regular;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 35px;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:#7d7b7c;
    padding:0;
}

/*** Fys Text ***/    
.fysbox {

    font-family:Exo-Regular;
    width:100%;
    height:850px;
    color:#7d7b7c;
    padding:0;
}
.fysbox h2 {
    font-size:40px;
    margin-left:35px;
}

.fysbox p {
    font-family:Exo-Regular;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 0 0 35px;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:#7d7b7c;
    padding:0;

}

.fysbox ul li {
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight:600;
}

    .textwrapper {
        width:100%;
        padding:20px;
}



/** Træning Text **/
.traeningbox p {
    font-family:Exo-Regular;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 35px;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#7d7b7c;
    padding:0;
}

.traeningbox h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left:35px;
}

    .traeningbox {
        width:90%;
    }


/*---- Priser Text ----*/
.textboxpris {
    float:left;
    font-family:Exo-Regular;
    width:350px;
    margin:0 0 0 35px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:#7d7b7c;
    padding:20px;
}

    .textboxpris p {
        font-size:33px;
    }

    .prish {
        width:188px;
    }

    .pristext {
        width:757px;
    }

.textboxpris h2 {
        font-size:40px;
}

.pristext {
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-top:100px;
}

.prispunkt {
        font-size:26px;
}

    .textwrapperpris {
        width:872px;
}

    .textwrapperpris h2 {

    }

.prisv {
    float:left;
    width:570px;
    height:200px;
}

.prisimgbox {
    visibility: hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

/*--- Kontakt text ---*/

.kontaktbox  {
    margin:0 0 0 98px;
    float:left;
    width:852px;
    height:600px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: Exo-Regular;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight:600;
}

.kontaktbox h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    iframe {
        display:none;
    }


.traeningimgbox {
    visibility: hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;

}

    footer {
        width:905px;
    }

}


And this is my HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slagelse Sportsklinik</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <a name="top"></a>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="Hlogobox">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logowhite.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="Hnavbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav1"><a href="#top"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fysmenu"><span>Fysioterapi</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#træningmenu"><span>Træning</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#prismenu"><span>Priser</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav5"><a href="#kontaktmenu"><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
                <a class="fblink" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/slagelsesportsklinik"><img class="fbicon" src="img/icons/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="contentblock1">
        <div class="contentwrapper">
         <div class="jonimgboxphone">
            <img class="jontitelphone" src="img/jontitel.png" alt="">
            <br>
            <img class="jonnicephone" src="img/jonnice.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="textbox">
            <p>
                <b>Slagelse Sportsklinik</b> startede i 2017 af fysioterapeut Jon Ahrensbøll med ønsket om at ville starte en klinik, der leverede hurtige og markante resultater, der skulle sikre hurtig tilbagevenden til idræt eller arbejde.
                <br>
                <br>
                <span class="jonahrensboll"><b>Jon Ahrensbøll</b></span> har igennem 18 år arbejdet som fysioterapeut på forskellige klinikker med alle typer af patienter. De senere år har patientgruppen primært været idrætsfolk primært indenfor triatlon, løb og cykling. Jon Ahrensbøll er samtidigt tilknyttet Gørlev Fysioterapi og Idrætsklinik som fysioterapeut med fysioterapeutisk ansvar for både Vestsjællands Idrætsefterskole og Gørlev Idrætsefterskole.

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="jonimgbox">
            <img class="jontitel" src="img/jontitel.png" alt="">
            <img class="jonnice" src="img/jonnice.png" alt="">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

         <div class="orangesplitter">
                                    <img class="splitter1" src="img/orangesplitter1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="splitter1mobile" src="img/orangesplitter1mobile.png" alt="">
         </div>

        <a name="fysmenu"></a>
         <span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>
        <div class="contentblock2">
        <div class="totalwrap">
         <div class="fysphone">
              <img class="img" src="img/jonbrugerlaser.png" alt="">
         </div>
           <div class="fysbox">
           <div class="textwrapper">

           <h2>Fysioterapi</h2>

            <p>
                Hos Slagelse Sportsklinik udfører vi fysioterapeutiske behandlinger af høj kvalitet. Vi har en høj grad af information om både tests og behandling, og vi tillægger altid et holistisk perspektiv i vores behandlinger.
               <br>
               <br>
                For at opnå størst mulig positiv effekt benytter vi forskellige fysioterapeutiske, osteopatiske og kiropraktiske manuelle teknikker, ligesom vi ofte inddrager forskellige former for træningsøvelser.
               <br>
               <br>
                Udover manuelle teknikker og træningsøvelser benytter vi desuden bl.a.

            </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>IMS (Intra Muskulær Stimulation) dvs. behandling med nåle, hvorved bl.a. muskulatur afspændes hurtigt.</li>
                    <li>Kinesiotape, dvs. optapening med hyperelastisk tape, der på en gang støtter og bibeholder fuld funktion af både muskler og led.</li>
                    <li>High Power Laser, dvs. laserbehandling, der skaber en kemisk modulering af vævet, så opheling sker markant hurtigere</li>
                </ul>
            </div>


         </div>
            <div class="fysimgbox">
              <img class="imgfys" src="img/jonbrugerlaser.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          <div class="greysplitter"><img class="splitter2" src="img/greysplitter1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="splitter2mobile" src="img/greysplitter1mobile.png" alt="">
          </div>

        <a name="træningmenu"></a>

        <span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>
        <div class="contentblock3" id="contentblock3">
        <div class="traeningbox">
          <div class="textwrapper">
           <h2>Træning</h2>
            <p>
               Hos Slagelse Sportsklinik tilbydes træning på små hold (max. 5 personer). Vi har forskellige former for holdtræning, og ens for dem alle er, at der er fokus på CORE, stabilitet og -ikke mindst- funktionalitet. Træningen er målrettet den enkelte deltager, således at alle uanset niveau vil blive udfordret.
                <br>
                <br>
                Vi har valgt små hold ud fra ideen om, at på små hold er det intensiv, nærmest personlig træning samtidigt med, at man fortsat kan være social.

                <br>
                <br>
                På alle hold benyttes styrke- og udspændingsøvelser hentet fra Pilates, Yoga og CORE, ligesom der benyttes træning i TRX, dvs. træning i slynger med egen kropsvægt som modstand.
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="traeningimgbox">
                <img src="img/grittoneddown.png" alt="">
                <img class="pushimg" src="img/stretch.png" alt="">
            </div>
         </div>
           <div class="orangesplitter">
                <img class="splitter3" src="img/orangesplitter2.png" alt="">
                <img class="splitter3mobile" src="img/orangesplitter2mobile.png" alt="">
          </div>
        <a name="prismenu"></a>
         <span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>


        <div class="contentblock">
          <div class="textboxpris">
          <div class="textwrapperpris">

           <h2>Priser</h2>

            <p class="prisv">
                Fysioterapeutisk behandling pr. gang <br><br>
                Træning pr. gang <br><br>
                Træningsklippekort - 10 gange <br><br>
                Behandlingsklippekort - 10 gange <br><br>
            </p>

            <p class="prispunkt">
                <b>•</b><br><br>
                <b>•</b><br><br>
                <b>•</b><br><br>
                <b>•</b><br><br>
            </p>

            <p class="prish">
               <b>kr. 275,00</b> <br><br>
               <b>kr. 45,00 </b><br><br>
               <b>kr. 400,00</b> <br><br>
               <b>kr. 2500,00</b> <br><br>
            </p>

            <p class="pristext">
              Slagelse Sportsklinik har <b>ikke</b> overenskomst med Den Offentlige Sygesikring, så tilskud hertil kan ikke opnås. Dette betyder samtidigt, at der ikke kræves henvisning fra egen læge for at kunne få behandling hos Slagelse Sportsklinik.
            </p>

            </div>
           </div>

               <div class="prisimgbox"><img src="img/transaction.png" alt="">

               </div>
          </div>


            <div class="greysplitter">
                    <img class="splitter4" src="img/greysplitter2.png" alt="">
                    <img class="splitter4mobile" src="img/greysplitter2mobile.png" alt="">
            </div>

        <a name="kontaktmenu"></a>
        <span class="anchor" id="section2"></span>
        <div class="contentblock" id="contentblock5">
            <div class="kontaktbox">
           <h2>Kontakt</h2>
            <p>
                Du kan kontakte klinikken på følgende måder:
            </p>
              <ul>
                  <li><p><b>Telefon</b></p></li>
                  <li><p><b>Mail</b></p></li>
                  <li><p><b>Snailmail</b></p></li><br><br>
                  <li><p><b>Facebook</b></p></li>
              </ul>
               <ul>
                  <li><p>2844 0023</p></li>
                  <li><p>slagelsesportsklinik@gmail.com</p></li>
                  <li><p>Slagelse Sportsklinik <br>
                          Nytorv 4, 1. sal <br>
                          4200 Slagelse</p></li>
                  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/slagelsesportsklinik">www.facebook.com/slagelsesportsklinik</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
             <iframe

                  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDXNF-E5Se1Suc6FWGmQWoH_bcpHoSwEEs
                    &q=Nytorv4+Slagelse,Slagelse+DK" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
       <div class="footerleft">
        <adress>Slagelse Sportsklinik</adress><br>
        <adress>Nytorv 4, 1. Sal</adress><br>
        <adress>4200 Slagelse</adress><br>
       </div>
       <div class="footerright">
        <img class="footericon" src="img/icons/tlf.png" alt=""><adress>2844 0023</adress><br><br>
        <img  class="footericon" src="img/icons/mail.png" alt=""><adress>slagelsesportsklinik@gmail.com</adress><br><br>
        <img  class="footericon" src="img/icons/fbsort.png" alt=""><adress><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/slagelsesportsklinik">www.facebook.com/slagelsesportsklinik</a></adress>  
       </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: To answer your question an MCVE is the most important thing, since reading **all** your css without any *result* it's really hard for us.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your container div, in this case `wrapper`, the following:

```
.wrapper {
   overflow:hidden;
   width:100%;
   max-width:1200px; // or whatever you want
   display:block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will contain everything inside your `wrapper` element and center it on the page for screen sizes greater than 1200px.

Also your `header` and `body` elements currently have fixed widths, you should remove the property from `body`, and give `header` a percentage-based width:

```
header {
   width:100%;
}
```